# using graalvm to convert jar to exe with all jars included

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I have created a jar file **abc.jar**. I want my jar to be converted to **.exe** file using the native-image command of graalvm. The jar needs some dependencies(external jars) to work.

So my command looks like:-

```
native-image -jar abc.jar output -cp "abc.jar;C:\lib\*"
```

The exe is generated and works on my machine. Nevertheless, when I ship it to a different matching and try to run the same it doesn't work unless I place all libs under **C:\lib** folder(the very same folder where I placed the external dependent jars). How can I create an executable with the jars included as part of exe file.

I tried the following specified in the [documentation](https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/Resources/) and no luck.

Regards.

Comment: One thing to note is that in general with java, the `-jar` and `-cp` argument don't work together. You can either use `-cp "abc.jar;C:\lib\*" abc.Main` or add the right `Class-Path` attribute in `abc.jar`'s manifest and then just use `-jar`. The `-cp` route might be easier since i'm not sure the `Class-Path` attribute supports wildcards.

Comment: @Dhana did you find a solution? I am facing the same issue